# Strange line when button is selected iOS

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, uiimage

I have different buttons with a custom image for each one.

When I press them I change the state to Selected and the image change successfully but next to the button appears a strange blue line.

How can remove it?

Before Select: [image]

After Select: [image]

**[Updated]**

The xib for the buttons is:

```
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0ob-Gu-D9L" userLabel="Xat">
                <rect key="frame" x="976" y="0.0" width="46" height="46"/>
                <state key="normal" title="Xat">
                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
            </button>
```

The code:

```
UIImage imageOn = UIImage.FromBundle(iconOn).ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);

 button.SetImage(imageOn, UIControlState.Normal);
```

Comment: Maybe, your image for the button's selected state is like that image?

Comment: No, I have tried changing the image and the result is the same.

Comment: Can you show your xib file or code where you create these buttons?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Updated!